# Extracting json when web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I was following a python guide on web scraping and there's one line of code that won't work for me. I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me figure out what the issue is, thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import requests

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('root\.App\.main'))

json_text = re.search(r'^\s*root\.App\.main\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*;\s*$',script.string, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)
```

Error Message:

```
    json_text = re.search(r'^\s*root\.App\.main\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*;\s*$',script.string, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Link to the guide I was looking at: https://www.mattbutton.com/how-to-scrape-stock-upgrades-and-downgrades-from-yahoo-finance/

Comment: We need a few more details to help you. What happens when you run this code? What do you want to do it instead? What does the `<script>` tag look like?

Comment: you could also use [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)

Answer (score 1):

Main issue in my opinion is that you should add an `user-agent` to your request, so that you get expected HTML:

```
headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Note:** *Almost and first at all - Take a deeper look into your soup, to check if expected information is available.*

##### Example

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'
headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('root\.App\.main'))

json_text = json.loads(re.search(r'^\s*root\.App\.main\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*;\s*$',script.string, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1))
json_text
```